# Capture live network traffic from a virtual machine using python

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualbox, scapy

i'm trying to capture the network traffic generated by my virtual machine only . On my physical system i'm using python 2.5 and scapy to capture packets from the physical system right now, but i noticed that its capturing the physical system's traffic also . I am using  the (pyvbox) virtualbox api to interface with the Oracle VirtualBox .

My VirtualBox network configurations are as follows :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a BPF filter. In Scapy:

```
sniff(..., filter='ether host 08:00:27:73:3c:46')
```

If for some reason that do not work, you can use the `lfilter` parameter (slower):

```
sniff(..., lfilter=lambda p: '08:00:27:73:3c:46' in [p.src, p.dst])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pyvbox you can capture network traffic from a network adapter as shown in this example: https://gist.github.com/mjdorma/9045130